Length of a line segment in a triangle?
How do you find the length of the line segment $EF$? $ABCD$ is a square. $AC = 60$ cm, $AE = 50$ cm. Background information: I needed two triangle tiles with sides $40$ cm and $50$ cm for my project and was wondering whether I could turn $60 \times 60$ tile into a triangle with sides $40$ cm and $50$ cm without too much effort.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

You have asked this question here. Please try to improve that question instead of posting a new one.

You should search for a lesson about Thales theorem...

Triangle $ACD$ and $AEF$ are similar triangles, which you can easily verify. After that just observe that $\dfrac{AE}{AC} = \dfrac{EF}{CD}$, which implies $EF = 50$.

I don’t think you have the correct second ratio. If you’re comparing $AE$ to $EC$, then you should compare $EF$ to $FG$, not $CD$.

Or maybe you meant to say $\frac{AE}{AC}=\frac{EF}{CD}$.

Yes, I am sorry it's my mistake. Thanks for pointing out

Afntu’s answer sums it up pretty well. I also wanted to add that if you cut off a $10\times 60$ strip from the top of the tile and a $20\times 60$ strip from the side, then you’ll be left with a $50\,\text{cm}\times 40\,\text{cm}$ rectangular tile. This will allow you to make one diagonal cut through opposite corners to obtain two triangles with side lengths $50\,\text{cm}$ and $40\,\text{cm}$, which was your original goal.

Note $$\angle EAF\equiv \angle CAD=\angle CDA=\angle EFA$$ where we used $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles (First equality) and $EF\|CD$ (Second equality).
Thus $\triangle EAF$ is E-isosceles so $$EF=AE=50$$

This may seem like a sort of silly answer, but in the spirit of multiple approaches: I think it's often wise to graph something in the plane. Even if you end up not finding a formal proof, you may get an idea about what sort of answer to look for.
I graphed your setup in Desmos and you can see how the various components intersect. Here is a screenshot of what you would find at that link:

